# How do I deprecate an attribute in a Moose based class

Tags: perl, attributes, deprecated, moose

I have a [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) [based class](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON%3a%3aRPC%3a%3aLWP), with a couple of attributes that I want to remove.

I want any use of them to generate a deprecation warning.
Possibly with a way to disable the warnings.

```
package JSON::RPC::LWP;
...
use Moose;
...

has previous_id => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => JSONValue,
  init_arg => undef,
  writer => '_previous_id',
  predicate => 'has_previous_id',
  clearer => 'clear_previous_id',
);

# default id generator is a simple incrementor
my $default_id_gen = sub{
  my($self,$prev) = @_;
  $prev ||= 0;
  return $prev + 1;
};

has id_generator => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Maybe[CodeRef]',
  default => sub{ $default_id_gen },
  trigger => sub{
    my($self,$coderef) = @_;
    unless( $coderef ){
      $self->{id_generator} = $default_id_gen;
    }
  },
);
```

I have already [removed the only place `id_generator` was used](https://github.com/b2gills/JSON-RPC-LWP/commit/91f756578eb0b493989b49294dd83a9daccf0ed0).

---

Right now the only known [user](https://github.com/tsee/Games-Lacuna-Client/blob/615723c45372424d73e760f47b39e33fbb5fdc96/lib/Games/Lacuna/Client/RPC.pm#L48) of this module sets `id_generator` to a code ref that effectively sets it to the future behaviour.
I have [modified](https://github.com/tsee/Games-Lacuna-Client/commit/74fa287f22ad54a4220c888a2c24989ab6925a63) it to only do this on older versions of my module. ( not yet released )

```
package Games::Lacuna::Client::RPC;
...
use Moose;

extends 'JSON::RPC::LWP';
...

has '+id_generator' => (
  default => sub{sub{1}},
);
```

Comment: congrats on being the #1337 user on stack overflow! you are 1337!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to do it! Use [MooseX::Deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/TOBYINK/MooseX-Deprecated-0.002/lib/MooseX/Deprecated.pm) :-)

```
with "MooseX::Deprecated" => {
   attributes => [ "id_generator" ],
};
```

I wrote MooseX::Deprecated inspired by my previous answer to this question. It encapsulates the application of method modifiers, checking init_args, fiddling with `%Carp::Internal` and `warnings::enabled`, all into one tidy little package.

Comment: The reason I have not accepted an answer is that I want any attempt to modify the default with `has '+id_generator' => ( default => sub{sub{1}});` to also produce a warning, and I was waiting for the possibility for one to show up.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a method modifier on the accessor:

```
before id_generator => sub
{
   require Carp;
   Carp::carp("The id_generator method is deprecated; called");
};
```

You can also issue a warning if it's passed to the constructor

```
after BUILD => sub
{
   my ($self, $params) = @_;
   if ($params->{id_generator})
   {
      require Carp;
      Carp::carp("The id_generator parameter to the constructor is deprecated; given");
   }
};
```

Yes, a MooseX module to do this would be nice.

For disableable warnings, look at `perldoc warnings`; in particular note what `warnings::enabled("deprecated")` returns.